# What generates btnotification_log.txt?

Tags: logging

On my son's Samsung Galaxy S3 smartphone, this file's size frequently rises to 4 or 5GB and I just delete it. Obviously it's just a log file. I want to strike at the root of the issue instead.

Comment: Bluetooth [bt]notification_log.txt logs other bluetooth devices within range of pairing. Bluetooth can be turned off, which is dramatic, or setting for bluetooth broadcasting. My S3 allows the setting for "make visible to other devices." to be turned off, though I believe your log is the result of other devices within range, so this may be an all-or-nothing thing.

Comment: By all-or-nothing, I mean turning off Bluetooth completely, rejecting the pairing requests from OTHER devices.

Comment: Isn't it extreme for this file to be growing so large over the course of several days? I need to measure how often it is but it seems monthly it's already up between 4GB or 5GB, taking up so much space and not allowing any installations or updates of other software as a result.

Comment: Well, probably everyone he comes into contact with daily (like school) have bluetooth-enabled devices broadcasting pair requests all day. Maybe multiple times per day, as they enter-and-leave range, which is about 10 meters. So, consider HUNDREDS of requests coming into view as bursts of activity all day long.

Comment: Phones are generally Class 2  bluetooth devices limited to 10 meters. Other devices, like Class 1 (100 meters) such as computers and laptops also can make pair requests. Also, Class 1 can be extended to 1 mile as I read in [this](https://www.sans.edu/cyber-research/security-laboratory/article/bluetooth) blog article.  Your son may be attracting pair requests much greater than that of just friends during the day, so that log could be very informative.

Comment: @ShieldOfSalvation does your son have a smartwatch paired? There are some Chinese ones using a companion app going by the name "BTNotification". Maybe that one is in debug/logging mode. If that app is installed, you could check its settings if that can be turned off.